# How can I filter between two datetime timestamps in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
     price_lvl_size_total  raw_end_of_event    receive_timestamp  
154                0              True        2023-05-29 00:15:01.000138338   
160                0              True        2023-05-29 00:15:01.138503551
```

And I would like to filter for rows between the above two timestamps.

I have tried:

```
dateframe.between_time(2023-5-29 00:15:01.000138338, 2023-05-29 00:15:01.138503551)
```

But I get a `invalid syntax` error. I have also tried putting the datetime inside strings but I get

```
TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex
```

Comment: Use `&` instead of `AND`. `AND` is syntactically wrong.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I actually get the second error now when I use `&`, even though the query doesn't complain about syntax error.

Comment: Verify that each condition should be inside `( )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to parse the timestamps first ? Anyways, you can try this :

```
# (if needed) to make sure the timestamps are cast to int64
# file["receive_timestamp"] = file["receive_timestamp"].astype("int64")
​
out = file.loc[file["receive_timestamp"].between(1685319301000138338, 1685319301138503551)]
​
#variant ?
out = file.loc[pd.to_datetime(file["receive_timestamp"]).dt.microsecond.between(138, 138503)]
```

Output :

```
print(out)
​
     price_lvl_size_total  raw_end_of_event    receive_timestamp
154                     0              True  1685319301000138338
160                     0              True  1685319301138503551
```

***Update :***

Regarding the updated question, you can use :

```
# (if needed)
#file["receive_timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(file["receive_timestamp"])

start, end = "2023-05-29 00:15:01.000138338", "2023-05-29 00:15:01.138503551"

out = file.loc[file["receive_timestamp"].between(start, end)]
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry I changed the question as I realised you're right about the parsing!

Comment: I'll give the above a try

Comment: No worries but can you give a meaningful example because it's not clear what's your trying to achieve.

Comment: It is exactly as per your answer. I want to retrieve all the rows inbetween the two given timestamps.

Comment: I updated my answer accordignly. Can you check it out ?